# How can my company benefit from employees participating in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I use Stack Overflow regularly during my work and also ask some questions. I wonder how my company can benefit from me and other employees who participate on Stack Overflow.

For example, if two or more people from different teams in the company are asking questions on the same topic, it would be good if they could know about each other. At the moment, though, I don’t see where they could get to know each other. Or the company could know the hot topics in which their developers are interested and could organize trainings on those topics.

So my question is, How can Stack Overflow be integrated into my company, so there is not only the benefit of a found answer or a answered question, but also benefits such as people from different teams finding each other to share knowledge.

I work for an IT service provider, and the teams often work at different customers on different locations, so communication between teams is a bit of a problem. I agree. But if ten devs are asking questions on [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) and another five ask questions about [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate), it probably would make sense to organize training for them. So probably having stats on the tags of a group of users is something that would make sense.

#### Clarification:

I think there is some misunderstanding here. I do not want Stack Exchange to be changed, nor am I requesting a new feature. I just wanted to know how I can use what already exists. I thought that the [discusson](/questions/tagged/discusson) tag and this site is also meant for discussions about Stack Overflow and how it may be used and integrated elsewhere.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are looking for here.

Comment: Ehm, can't you just have your teams communicate with each other? I hardly think that Stack Overflow should be a replacement/solution for that.

Comment: What benefits above and beyond what SO already provides are you looking for?

Comment: @Bart id don't want stackoverflow to be a replacement for communication. I just want some possiblity to know whats going on in the company or in the heads of the devs.

Comment: Then talk to them. Stack Overflow does not have (and most likely will never have) the "social" type of features you're talking about. At most you can ask each employee to provide their profile and you can follow their user feeds. But that's about it and by no means a replacement for good communication.

Comment: @Bart that is probably an answer I was looking for with this question.

Comment: How can Stack Overflow can be integrated into your company? However you want to, but that's not the purpose of the site and the site isn't going to change to help you do so.

Comment: If you're looking for reasons why your company should support using stack overflow; constantly being exposed to new questions and answers increases your skill level and keeps you up to date with new technology (I've already answered questions on Java 8, without stack overflow I probably wouldn't even be aware of it). However; I can't see any benefit of you interacting on the site beyond normal interactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your employees all give you their user id numbers you could use the SO API to programmatically make your own external social tool.  You could provide a list of all of the questions asked by a user in your company, see what they are answering, look at the tags they are most active in asking/answering, etc.

You could do something as formal as making your own social networking site with this data, or something as simple as taking a data dump every so often, putting it in a database, and running a few ad hoc queries whenever you're interested.

Comment: And while at that, also ask for their names at Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, ..., so you know what they like to have for lunch. Alternatively: just ask people what they would like to be trained in? (Far less intrusive too, I feel, as nobody would feel troubled when rejecting the request.)

Comment: @Arjan I'm merely indicating that it's possible; not that it's the desirable way of determining what training to schedule for your employees.  I leave such decisions up to people who actually are burdened with such decisions.

Comment: (I know, my comment was not really directed to you. Sorry about that!)

Answer (score 4):

About as far as SO/SE goes in providing the means to "follow" users is via user feeds. These feeds are accessible from the user's profile. Given this, you could ask each employee to voluntarily provide their account details and you could perhaps monitor this activity.

But that is about as far as this will most likely go. Any "social" features beyond this are very unlikely to ever be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

> For example, if two or more people from different teams in the company are asking questions on the same topic, it would be good if they could know about each other.

Oh, look, it seems this got implemented! [Stack Overflow for Teams is Now Available](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/)
.